# How to check if a blank DVD is damaged?

Tags: burning, dvd-burning

Today I burned a DVD, but when I insert it into my external DVD drive I am told that it is blank, but if I try to burn something else on it, it simply gets ejected.

The DVD in question is a -R Dual Layer, which my DVD drive has no problems in handling. The DVD drive is a [Samsung SE-208AB](http://www.samsung.com/sg/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/optical-disc-drive/slim-dvd-writer/SE-208AB/TSBSA).

Is there a way to check exactly what kind of problem this is?

Comment: Please update with the type of dvd disc (R+ or R-, or Dual layer), and if your external dvd drive can read those type of dvd's (the model of the dvd drive is fine if you don't know how to tell).

Comment: @MDMoore313 I've updated the question with the type of disc and the drive model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows you could try out [IsoBuster](http://www.isobuster.com/isobuster.php). It has features such as sector view, surface scan etc.

Comment: Do you happen to know a free alternative?

Comment: No, sorry. But as far as I know you can use IsoBuster without registering. Some features might be disabled though.